# Recursive Function to Traverse Binary Tree

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, recursion, binary-tree

I have mySQL table like:

```
userid left_refid right_ref_id
1             3        4
3             5        6
```

and so on. I want to go through the binary tree and display all userid, and left and right ref ids.

This is the code I used, but it prints **134** continuously.

```
function display_childs($parent) {

    //$result = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM tree WHERE parent=".$parent.'";'); 
    global $wpdb;
    $prefix=$wpdb->prefix;
    if($parent==0){
        $parent=3;
    }
    $user_ref_1 = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_user_reference WHERE user_id=".$parent."" ));

    foreach($user_ref_1 as $urd)
    {
        echo $urd->user_id;
        echo $urd->left_zone_id;
        echo $urd->right_zone_id;
        echo '<br>'; 
        $user_idpass=$urd->user_id;
    }

    display_childs($user_idpass); 
    unset($user_idpass);
    unset($parent);
}

display_childs(0);
```

Comment: What result are you getting and what result do you want?

Comment: it prints 134 continuously,i want to print the all  userid,and left right ref ids..,

Comment: I editied your question to clarify that. You should double-check and make sure I got it right. Also, consider reading [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current function recursively calls itself `display_childs($user_idpass);`, however this will always be called with the 'parent' id and never the 'child' ids

Within the `foreach` loop you should also be calling `display_childs($urd->left_zone_id)` and `display_childs($urd->right_zone_id)` (and remove the call to `display_childs($user_idpass);`)

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: the way the OP has put in the recursive call, it will always query the 'parent' node and never the 'child' nodes unless he calls the function with their id

Answer (score 2):

Normally this tree doesn't support recursion  but you can try the between operator in the where clause: select  * from where left_ref_id between 3, 7 and right_ref_id between 3,7 to pull the children. Look for a nested set table or a celko tree.

Update: You can also try to recursively call 'display_childs($urd->left_zone_id)`and`display_childs($ur->right_zone_id)` in the for-loop.